# Function Jquery para selecionar tab com campos required não preenchidos

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Utilizo a tab do `bootstrap` e o `required` do `dataannotations`,
porém acontece o seguinte, não da pra saber os campos do required, quando não está na `tab` dele, por exemplo, estou na `tab` 1, e concluo, porém na 2 campos com `required` não estão preenchidos, não da pra saber, eu gostaria que fosse para `tab` onde os campos com `required` não foram preenchidos.

Eu tentei este código, tanto no `submit` e com o click do `button`, porém não funcionou:

```
$('#btnConcluir').click(function () {
        $('input:invalid').each(function () {
            // Find the tab-pane that this element is inside, and get the id
            var $closest = $(this).closest('.tab-pane');
            var id = $closest.attr('id');

            // Find the link that corresponds to the pane and have it show
            $('.nav a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');

            // Only want to do it once
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Tentei este aqui também:

```
 $('#btnConcluir').click(function () {
        console.log('entrou');
        $(':required:invalid', '#FornecedorNovo').each(function () {
            var id = $('.tab-pane').find(':required:invalid').closest('.tab-pane').attr('id');

            $('.nav a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Mariana, o `:invalid` funciona com campos onde possui o atributo `required`. Não tenho conhecimento sobre esse recurso que vc está usando, o `dataannotations`. Se fosse só pelo `required` do HTML5 esse seu código deveria funcionar perfeitamente, e detalhe: esse laço `each` nem é necessário, basta ver se `$('input:invalid', '#FornecedorNovo').length` é true ou false que ele já acha o campo vazio.

Comment: @sam vou fazer um teste desta forma, tem alguma ideia de alguma forma que eu posso verificar?

Comment: @sam eu fiz o teste e não funcionou, o console ele só valida os campos do tab selecionado, e não de todos.

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma solução com [Jquery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```js
$('#validate').validate({
  ignore: [],
  errorPlacement: function() {},
  submitHandler: function() {
    alert('Cadastro salvo com sucesso');
  },
  invalidHandler: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.nav-tabs a small.required').remove();
      var validatePane = $('.tab-content.tab-validate .tab-pane:has(input.error)').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.nav-tabs').find('a[href^="#' + id + '"]').append(' <small class="required">*</small>');
        $('.nav-tabs').find('a[href^="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
      });
    });
  },
  rules: {
    name: 'required',
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    zipcode: 'required',
    address: 'required',
    city: 'required'
  }
});
```

```css
input.error {
  border-color: #f00 !important;
}

small.required {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">

  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      Formulário de cadastro
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form action="" class="form-horizontal" id="validate">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified nav-inline">
          <li class="active"><a href="#primary" data-toggle="tab">Informações do contato</a></li>
          <li><a href="#secondary" data-toggle="tab">Informações de endereço</a></li>
        </ul>


        <div class="tab-content tab-validate" style="margin-top:20px;">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="primary">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name" class="control-label col-md-2">Nome</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email" class="control-label col-md-2">E-mail</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="secondary">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="zipcode" class="control-label col-md-2">CEP</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="zipcode" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="address" class="control-label col-md-2">Endereço</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="city" class="control-label col-md-2">Cidade</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2 pull-right">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Salvar</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ele não seleciona a tab que está faltando ser preenchida, não tem a forma de fazer isso ?

Comment: @marianac_costa. Dá sim. Eu alterei a resposta e vê se te atende. Att,

Comment: Será que eu consigo adaptar para verificar o required do `dataannotations` ?

Comment: @marianac_costa você querer dizer required do dataannotations do ASP NET MVC? Ou o atributo required do HTML?

Comment: Do ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Não resolve removendo os atributos do elemento:

```
            $('#Salvar').removeAttr('type', 'submit');
            $('#Salvar').removeClass('data-toggle', 'title');
            $('#Salvar').addClass('disabled');
            $('#Salvar').removeAttr('type', 'submit');
```

E depois apenas atribui caso todos os campos obrigatórios estejam preenchidos, uma outra coisa que fiz aqui na empresa foi criar uma função para o usuário ir para tab2 apenas se tiver preenchidos todos os campos da tab1, mas na tab2 fiz assim e caso venha aparecer uma outra forma mais elegante mudarei para essa solução.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que voce quis fizer Adriano, eu preciso que dê focus e selecione a tab onde possui campos sem preenchidos que possuem o required. Neste exemplo ele apenas remove o type submit.

Comment: Então, você terá que criar uma função para saber qual o índice da tab para verificar se os campos estão preenchidos daquela tab.

Comment: Eu fiz os testes aqui Adriano, na função que coloquei na pergunta ele só entra da tab selecionada, e eu gostaria que ele validasse de todos os campos, por isso não está funcionando, ele está reconhecendo somente os campos da tab selecionada.